# Why CREATE VIEW must be first statement in a batch?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any logical reason for which CREATE VIEW must be first statement in a batch? What is a rationale behind such design?

Comment: if we're talking TSQL, you're probably missing a `GO` before/after the `CREATE VIEW`. SQL builds queries based on delimiters so omitting them makes SQL unsure as to what's part of the view and what's another statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not so much that it must be the *first* statement in the batch, but rather that it must be the *only* statement in the batch. For the same reason `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `CREATE FUNCTION`, etc. all have to be in their own batch ... they need to be compiled independently of other code. One reason is to ensure that anything in the batch created *before* the object actually exists when it is created, and anything that refers to the object *afterward* has something to point to. Another is to help prevent this stuff:

```
-- some other code here

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
AS
  -- procedure code here

-- some other code here
```

We don't want "some other code here" to be included in the definition of the stored procedure. We also wouldn't know what to do with this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc1
AS
  -- some code here
-- a comment here
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc2
AS
```

Since we can legally place comments *before* `CREATE PROCEDURE`, how does the parser know which object the comment belongs to?

And for the nit-picky, the same thing applies to views. (Note that a procedure was used in the example simply because a procedure can contain multiple statements while a view can't; and a procedure with multiple statements is far more common than a view with multiple comments.) But we can demonstrate the same type of problem - ask yourself if you don't separate the two views into their own batches, how do you know which view should own `comment4`?

```
-- comment1
CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
AS
  -- comment2
  SELECT 
  -- comment3
  * from sys.objects
  -- comment4
CREATE VIEW dbo.view2
AS
  -- comment5
  SELECT 
  -- comment6
  * from sys.objects
```

In Management Studio, you work around this by placing a `GO` between object scripts. Note that `GO` is not T-SQL, it is an app-specific batch separator; from other interfaces, you will need to transmit your batches separately in other ways.

Again, the answer is in the first sentence: a script to create or alter any module in SQL Server - including views, procedures, functions, and triggers - **must be the *only* statement in the batch**.

Comment: The topic is why 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a batch, why are you talking about stored procedures instead of views?

Comment: @Sergio because all modules in SQL Server follow the same rules - CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE FUNCTION - they all have to be the only statement in the batch. Maybe you could explain to me why my answer - which I answered in the first sentence - is worth a down-vote simply because I added an additional example that happened to use PROCEDURE instead of VIEW? Do you want me to change those to VIEW even though they don't change *the actual answer*? The reason the example demonstrates the problem is a procedure can have more than one statement but a view can't.

Comment: Sorry, at first it looked to me that it was a digression in a matter different than what was being questioned. If all the modules in SQL follow the same rules I suppose what you explain for PROCEDURES is also valid for Views.

Comment: `how do you know which view should own comment4?` Well, naturally I'd say with a semicolon to mark the end of one command between the two `CREATE VIEW`s

Comment: @DarkTrick semi-colons are still optional, unfortunately, and they mark the end of a _statement_, not of a batch or module. You can also put as many semi-colons in a row as you want, so what if there were three semi-colons on the line before `-- comment4` and four on the line after it?